tblr-extras, how to put caption below table
With tblr-extras you can use caption package for set up caption style. It works fin, if caption is above table. For example:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[font={footnotesize, sf, stretch=0.80},
            labelfont = bf]{caption}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{tblr-extras}        % <---  
\UseTblrLibrary{caption}        % <---

\begin{document}
\lipsum[66]
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
\begin{talltblr}[
caption = {\lipsum[66]}
                ]{width=0.88\textwidth,
                  colspec = {*{4}{ X[c]}},
                  hlines, vlines
                 }
1  & 2 & 3 & 4  \\   
1  & 2 & 3 & 4  \\   
\end{talltblr}
    \end{table}
\lipsum[66]
\end{document}

gives

What I should do, that caption will appear below table. For example, by using
\DefTblrTemplate{firsthead,middlehead,lasthead}{default}{}
\DefTblrTemplate{firstfoot,middlefoot}{default}{}   
\DefTblrTemplate{lastfoot}{default}{\UseTblrTemplate{caption}{default}}

before talltblr move caption below table, however this caption not consider layout defined by caption package anymore but make caption as it is coded in talltblr:

What to do?

As a quick and dirty hack, you could use a note:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[font={footnotesize, sf, stretch=0.80},
            labelfont = bf]{caption}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{tblr-extras}% <---  
\UseTblrLibrary{caption}% <---

\DefTblrTemplate{firsthead,middlehead,lasthead}{default}{}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[66]
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{talltblr}[
  label=none,
  note{b}={text},
  note{a}={text},
  note{}={\captionof{table}{\lipsum[66]}}
]{
  width=0.88\textwidth,
  colspec = {*{4}{ X[c]}},
  hlines, vlines
}
1  & 2 & 3 & 4  \\
1  & 2 & 3 & 4  \\
\end{talltblr}
\end{table}
\lipsum[66]
\end{document}



Thank you very much! Yes, this is a interesting, simple way to solve a problem.  Good to know. In general, talltblr   has not native way to write caption below table (as this is not good practice. Where than should be placed  standard notes and remarks? With accepting of answer I will wait a day or two.

If you place the caption in the last note, normal notes will be shown above it.

Of course! You are right. Anyway, personally at tables I always have caption above table. This problem I wow here on side in one question ...

BTW, with your solution the table still has  label Table above table ... To remove it you need to add \DefTblrTemplate{firsthead,middlehead,lasthead}{default}{} before talltblr. However, numbering still not work correctly. I will return to you answer laete evening

@Zarko Use label=none for the numbering

Yes, this helps! (I wrongly  try  caption=none, ). And thank you for editing/completing answer. Now work as desired.

@Zarko You're welcome!

I am already working in support for no caption when label=none is used and a Boolean to select if caption is typeset above or below tabularrays but I am having trouble retrieving the value of the label key and the value of the position key of caption. Sorry!

I have tried to add full support for captions below tables but that has posed some challenges of its own:

Table links in the list of tables always point to the lastpage of a
tblr. That is not a problem for single page tblr (talltblr) environments,
but is an issue for longtblr.

Table links always point to the caption and not to the start of the
table.

Spacing is inconsistent between firstfoot, middlefoot and lastfoot. So there is not guarantee about similar spacing using tabular and caption, and tblr with tblr-extras caption library.

I didn't find info or documentation about caption@iftop command, so I was unable to add automatic detection of the value of position key in captionsetup. To enable captions below tables with tblr-extras you need to use \TblrCaptionBelow. Default position is above and you can restore that configuration with \TblrCaptionAbove.


So, captions below tables are partially supported right now, without a ETA for full support, because I need to redesign / improve how tblr-extras is implemented. Suggestion are welcome as always
Anyway, you can download tblr-extras-dev in the repo of tblr-extras
And for sake of completeness, a MWE and a screenshot of the output:
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{caption}
    \captionsetup{labelfont=bf,justification=raggedleft,singlelinecheck=false,position=below,skip=4pt}
\usepackage{tblr-extras-dev} % Will be eventually \usepackage{tblr-extras}
\UseTblrLibrary{caption}
    \TblrCaptionBelow % Put captions below table
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\begin{document}

    \listoftables

    \clearpage
    
    A table ref: \ref{tableA}.
    
    \medspace

    \centering
    \begin{talltblr}[
        caption = {Title of table},
        entry = {Entry of table},
        label = tableA,
        remark{Note} = {Stuff to be a tablenote},
        note{a} = {Stuff to be a cellnote},
        % entry = none,
        % label = none,
        ]{
            colspec = X[c]X[c]X[c],
            hlines, vlines,
        }
        A\TblrNote{a} & B & C \\
        A & B & C \\
        A & B & C \\
        A & B & C \\
        A & B & C \\
        A & B & C \\
        A & B & C \\
        A & B & C \\
        A & B & C \\
    \end{talltblr}
\end{document}


